# Spanish characters are not storing in Oracle by ADODB+php

Tags: php, oracle, adodb, oci8

I am using Spanish characters in my application. Currently I am storing Spanish accents like this in to database

```
 &eacute; &iacute; &oacute; &uacute;testestet
```

If I am using query from database like this

```
UPDATE indi_cmi_unidad
    SET 
        nombre='Oscar:Oscar: Oscar:    é í ó ú',
        factor='0',
        indi_unidad_base='',
        abreviatura='tc'
    WHERE idunidad='3'
```

Then it is Okey it will save this characters[image]

But when I am passing this query from ADODB + PHP, then it is reflecting special character in database like,

[image]

I tried a lot 
I also put this query in my constructor class of  adodb

```
$sql = "ALTER SESSION SET NSL_CHARACTERSET = 'US7ASCII'";
```

But not getting any result.
Please help me

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What type of `DB collation` are you using?

Comment: I think my current NSL_CHARACTERSET is win1252
about collation I dont know

Comment: Why don't you change the charset to utf-8?

Comment: @JoanManuelHernández Sir I am using Oracle database , on shared server

Comment: Ok, sorry if this does not work but Oracle DB accepts universal character set... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/applocaledata.htm#NLSPG589

Comment: problem is not with Oracle my databse having this charactors, but not accepring from PHP

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the correct charset on the connection to the database ?

http://www.php.net//manual/es/function.oci-connect.php

Check the character_set parameter.

Something like this should work:

```
$connection = oci_connect(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_CONN_STRING, 'WE8ISO8859P15');
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```